# RabbitMQ Http Authentication Backend with SSL

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

When I try to configure the `rabbitmq_auth_backend_http` as described [here](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/tree/master/deps/rabbitmq_auth_backend_http) it gives me the following errors:

```
rabbit-1_1  | 22:12:08.330 [error] You've tried to set rabbitmq_auth_backend_http.ssl_options.cacertfile, but there is no setting with that name.
rabbit-1_1  | 22:12:08.330 [error] Did you mean one of these?
rabbit-1_1  | 22:12:08.560 [error]      auth_ldap.ssl_options.cacertfile
[...]
```

Without SSL it works fine. So the plugin is loaded and working. Just configuring SSL client authentication fails for me.
Am I missing something?

Comment: I am not sure if all properties need to be provided in the .schema file of the plugin, but if so, then they are definitely missing =/

Comment: When I add the configuration via the advanced.config classic style, the errors disappear but it still looks like the ssl_options are not taking effect.

Comment: With advanced.config, I got it working now. It was some other misconfiguration. 
Another thing I stumbled upon: Using SSL (without Client authentication), the request work, even without given the RabbitMQ the right CA certificate.